# VBA to repeatedly copy different combination of 2 sheets from one master workbook to new workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have one workbook with many sheets we'll call "type A" and an equal amount of "type B" sheets in the same workbook that correspond to a given type A sheet.

For simplicity, lets say my sheets go: red, yellow, blue, dark red, dark yellow then dark blue. I want to copy both red sheets to a brand new workbook, then both yellows to a different new workbook, and so on. I also want the name of the new workbook file to be the name of the type A file (e.g. Red). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the VBA I have so far. I am able to copy the first combo to a new workbook (i.e. both reds) but after that I receive a "424" error. I am using an "i" loop and referencing sheets by their number for simplicity/generalization.

```
Sub export2sheets()
Dim twb As Workbook
Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Integer
XPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = 1 To 2
    twb.Activate
    Worksheets(Array(i, (i + 2))).Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
         Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=XPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
         Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End With
    Workbooks.Add
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT 1**: the code below works but it does not name the file or close it as intended, ostensibly because I removed the lines of code to do so.

```
Sub export2sheets()
Dim twb As Workbook
Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Integer
XPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = 1 To 2
    twb.Activate
    Worksheets(Array(i, (i + 3))).Copy
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**: Most recent code is below.

- I have used `n` to generalize the number of files/type A sheets.
- I have removed anything related to `xPath`.
- I have changed `xWs` to `Worksheets(i)`.
- I have removed `Application.ActiveWorkbook`.
- i have changed `Close False` to `Close True` because I want it to
  close the file when finished.

**Any ideas** why the code is giving me a "52" error code when pressing F8 at the `SaveAs` line? It currently executes up until `SaveAs`, thus it does not change the filename or close the file. Also, for some reason `Save` and `Close False` work, but if either `SaveAs` or `Close True` is used, it does not work.

```
Sub export2sheets()
    Dim twb As Workbook
    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    n = 3 'set n = the number of type A files
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 1 To n
        twb.Worksheets(Array(i, (i + n))).Copy
        SaveAs Filename:=Worksheets(i).Name & ".xlsx"
        Close True
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What line do you receive your error on? When you say that the sheets are that color, do you mean that the tab color is red, a large portion of the cells are red, etc ?

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify: When my cursor is on the **first** `Application.ActiveWorkbook...` line and I press F8, I receive the 424 error. And I just colored a couple cells in each worksheet for simplicity.

Comment: Ah, 2 big things. You're relying too heavily on the `ActiveWorkbook`, you should instead make a `Workbook` variable to store the 'current' workbook you're working on

Comment: and 2, when you use the `With` statement you don't have to re-specify the previous properties. So, for example you can change `Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=XPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"` to `.SaveAs Filename:=XPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"`

Comment: take a look at this classic post to see why you really shouldn't use `ActiveWorkbook`, `Select`, or `Activate` to name a few unless you have no other choice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: I will try to implement your feedback and respond shortly. Additionally, please see my edit to my post above. I removed the lines intended to name and close the file, causing my code to run successfully (minus naming and closing the file). So as you pointed out, it appears the `ActiveWorkbook` part is the issue.

Comment: Yeah, while trimming off the `Application.ActiveWorkbook` part of those two lines might make the original 'work' (excluding the color renaming), there are several parts about it that I couldn't recommend keeping :)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Thank you very much for your suggestions. I have made a second **EDIT** to my post above with new code implementing your feedback but I am gettting a "52" error at the `SaveAs` line. This seems like a simple fix but I'm having trouble figuring out what the issue is.

Comment: you're making progress for sure! your current problem is that you need a second workbook variable that you can paste into and then save and close.

Comment: After a lot of reworking, I tried reworking my `SaveAs` line and successfully used this line instead `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Worksheets(i).Name`. Although `Close True` still isn't working, I wont mind just closing a bunch of documents since they're already saved. Thank you for your help. I'll mark this as resolved.

Comment: Can't mark it as resolved without an actual answer :P If you wanted to delete and repost the question I wouldn't mind taking a crack at it, but the thing is that you'll have to split this into 2 questions - the first asking how you can copy a worksheet over, and the second asking how to pick them out by color

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I am honestly not sure how I mark this as solved and give you credit since I am new to the site.

Comment: Don't worry I only gave you a bit of advice, you deserve the credit. You can't mark it resolved unless I add an actual 'answer' instead of just commenting

Comment: All right cool I won't worry about it. Thanks!